# Notice: Undefined index: CodUsua

Tags: php, html

Hice un botón el cual al presionarlo me mande a la parte superior del sitio y al presionarlo me sale el siguiente error

> Notice: Undefined index: CodUsua in C:\xampp\htdocs\LF\html\perfil.php
>   on line 236

Éste es el código:

```
<?php
PRINT <<<HERE
<form method="get" action="#inicio">

<button type="submit">

 <b class="hola2">Ir arriba</b>
</button>
             </form>
             <br>
HERE;


 ?>

  <a name="inicio"></a>

<?php if($_GET['CodUsua'] != $_SESSION['CodUsua']): ?>
        <?php if(empty($verificar_amigos)): ?>
            <li> <a class=" icon-user-plus " href="perfil.php?CodUsua=<?php echo $_GET['CodUsua']; ?>&&agregar=<?php echo $_GET['CodUsua']; ?>"> Agregar </a></li>
        <?php elseif($verificar_amigos[0]['status'] == true): ?>
            <li><a class="icon-users" href="#"> Amigos </a></li>
            <li> <a class=" icon-user-minus " href="perfil.php?CodUsua=<?php echo $_GET['CodUsua']; ?>&&Eliminar=<?php echo $_GET['CodUsua']; ?>"> Eliminar amigo </a></li>
            <?php elseif($verificar_amigos[0]['status'] == false and $_SESSION['CodUsua'] == $verificar_amigos[0]['usua_enviador'] ): ?>
            <li> <a  href="perfil.php?CodUsua=<?php echo $_GET['CodUsua']; ?>&&cancelar=<?php echo $_GET['CodUsua']; ?>"> Cancelar solicitud de amistad </a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Solicitud enviada</a></li>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <li><a href="../html/editarperfil.php"><span class="icon-pencil2"></span> Editar</a></li>
        <li><a href="../html/editpass.php"><span class="icon-lock"></span> Cambiar contraseña</a></li>
        <li><a href="../html/editarfoto.php"><span class=" icon-image "></span>  Cambiar foto de perfil</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li > <a class="icon-users" class="amigos"  href="amigos.php?CodUsua=<?php echo $_GET['CodUsua']; ?>"> Ver amigos <?php 
                        if(!empty(amigos::cantidad_amigos($_GET['CodUsua'])))
                            echo amigos::cantidad_amigos($_GET['CodUsua'])[0][0];
                        else echo 0;
                     ?> </a></li>
    </div>
</div>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: ¿Tu código es PHP? No entiendo el sentido de esto: `PRINT <<<HERE...` y de esto `&&agregar="> Agregar`. El error indica que en la URL actual no existe ningún valor llamado `CodUsua`, que intentas obtener aquí:  `echo amigos::cantidad_amigos($_GET['CodUsua'])[0][0];` Tu código es bastante extraño en varios puntos.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, `PRINT <<<HERE` hace uso de dos características de PHP: nº1) Las [funciones de usuario](http://fr.php.net/functions.user-defined) y construcciones del lenguaje son insensibles a mayúsculas/minúsculas, pero se recomienda usar la manera en la que están definidas o en minúsculas y nº2) PHP puede hacer uso de [heredoc](http://php.net/types.string#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) para definir cadenas. Duele los ojos ver un uso así de `print` y puede llevar a confusión, pero es válido :(

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que cuando no existe el parámetro GET `CodUsua` en la URL intentas acceder a él igualmente. PHP lanza una advertencia siempre que trates de acceder al índice de una matriz que no existe para advertirte que ésto podría llevarte a un error no controlado en tu aplicación.

Para detectar cuándo un índice de una matriz existe o no antes de acceder a su valor debes hacer uso de [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['CodUsua']) && ($_GET['CodUsua'] != $_SESSION['CodUsua'])): ?>
```

Donde la evaluación fallará si no existe el índice antes de acceder a él. Esto es así porque en una operación booleana `&&` ([`Y` lógico](http://php.net/operators.logical)) se detiene la evaluación del resto de operandos ([se evalúan de derecha a izquierda](http://php.net/operators.precedence)) en cuanto hay uno que vale `false`.

Otra zona donde no compruebas la validez del parámetro es ésta:

```
<li><a class="icon-users" class="amigos" href="amigos.php?CodUsua=<?=
  htmlspecialchars(isset($_GET['CodUsua'])?$_GET['CodUsua']:'')
?>">Ver amigos <?php 
  if(isset($_GET['CodUsua'])) && !empty(amigos::cantidad_amigos($_GET['CodUsua']))) {
    echo amigos::cantidad_amigos($_GET['CodUsua'])[0][0];
  } else {
    echo 0;
  }
?> </a></li>
```

Entiendo que quieres acceder a `$_SESSION['CodUsua']` en vez de a `$_GET['CodUsua']` para acceder a los amigos de tu código de usuario.

Además, he agregado [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para recordarte que toda salida al navegador debería pasar por esta función. El contenido de la variable súper global `$_GET` no la controlas, por lo que [podrían hacerte XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) fácilmente.

He hecho uso del [operador ternario `?:`](http://php.net/operators.comparison#language.operators.comparison.ternary) para que en caso de que el índice no exista devuelva una cadena vacía, pero queda en tu mano adoptar otra solución en caso de que ésta no exista.

Answer (score -3):

Al momento de presionar el botón, la variable GET CodUsua desaparece de la URL, y por eso PHP se queja de que no existe.

Agregá una arroba antes de cada referencia a **$_GET['CodUsua']** para que PHP no muestre errores cuando no existe. Tendría que quedar **@$_GET['CodUsua']**

Comment: El uso de @ es una práctica **no recomendada**... -1